# How to send messages to a sub socket running in docker container from host?

Tags: sockets, docker, zeromq

I have a publisher running on `host` on port `N`.

It would be painful to pack into container.

And I have a subscriber running inside a container.

The problem is that if I first run the publisher on `host`, then I can't export ports in `docker run -d -p N:N publisher` (where `N` is the port number)

```
Error response from daemon:    Cannot start container 41202025441bf02ad5c8cf2a85fb1f1bd04c2211e648f5ec446442f9af4a6274:
Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:5570:
                               bind: address already in use
```

And if I first start container, then there would be an `Address already in use` error in publisher.

The problem I think is that when docker exposing port from container to host in binds to them somehow. So no one else can bind to that port in host.

Can I do something aside running publisher in container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your docker demon is running with **`--icc=true`** (communication between containers/network) and the docker0 network adapter is successfully added to your host **`iptables`** config (Usually done by docker parameter **`--iptables=true`** ).

Then run your container with **`-p N`** (not `N:N`). This means that the port is ***exposed*** and ***not*** mapped on a host port.

Then look for the containers ip address:

```
$ docker inspect publisher
```

Now contact your subscriber not by **`localhost`**`:5570` but <kbd>`ip-adress`</kbd>**`:5570`**.

Comment: It's not the publisher running inside of container but subscriber.
Basically  I think the only way to do this is not to map ports from subscriber container but to know hosts ip inside of container and connect to it. But this is... just wrong I think. I think I should just dockerize publisher.

Answer (score 0):

when you do N:N, port is well binded with host. You might have a running container already using this port. Try `docker ps -a` to see if there is one container running with that port. If one, kill it.